# How to fix the UIImage overlapping in UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code:

```
// Declare a UIImageView, set its frame and add an image to it
var myImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
myImageView.image = UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"myImage"))

// Let's add the UIImageView to the alertController
alertController.view.addSubview(myImageView)
```

However, the view is overlapping the `UIAlertController`:

[image: img1]

How can I fix it?

Comment: My guess is that you've got an incomplete block/expression on the lines immediately preceding the `imageView` declaration, as this code, in isolation is fine.

Comment: FWIW, in swift you should just use one of the `CGRect` constructor's instead of calling `CGRectMake`.  You can also optimize the `UIImageView` creation as `UIImageView(image:UIImage(named:"upgrade1Image"))` which will automatically size the image view for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've no business adding subview to an alert view. It is easy to make a view-controlled presented view that behaves like an alert view, and that's what you should do. That way, you are in charge of the view and you won't have any problems laying it out in a nib / storyboard with autolayout or whatever.

Comment: I just bought your iOS 9 Swift programming book and it's crazy good. That means no more asking silly questions as the one above.